# List size per sqlite column

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have imported a list with characters, the list size reaching about 100 MB, into a column in sqlite3 DB.

When I iterate through the list, its fast enough, but opening the database takes too long.

Is there a maximum or limit size per column?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html might be worth a read

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "opening"?